# Go Daddy's intermediate CA certificate missing

Tags: windows-10, godaddy, pki, certificate-authority

**An unaffected PC** (Windows 10 Pro connected to AD DS domain)

[image]
[image]

**Affected PCs** (Windows 10 Pro standalones)

[image]
[image]
[image]

What could cause intermediate but not root CA certificates to be missing?

I've verified that local policy `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Internet Communication Management\Internet Communication settings\Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update` isn't configured.

I've verified that Windows service `Cryptographic Services` / `CryptSvc` is running and restarting it didn't make a difference.

I've found that no relevant events are logged, as far as I can see.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3004394/support-for-urgent-trusted-root-updates-for-windows-root-certificate-p says:

> The Windows Root Certificate Program enables trusted root certificates
>   to be distributed automatically in Windows. Usually, a client computer
>   polls root certificate updates one time a week.

How do you manually force an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server providing a TLS/SSL connection (as in a HTTPS web-server) should send the client *all* certificates in the chain.  That is, the end-entity certificate, all subordinate CAs and optionally (but not mandatory) the Root CA certificate.

Your so called *Affected PCs* are showing the symptom of a web-server that has been misconfigured and is simply sending the end-entity certificate.  Your browser gets this certificate and has no way to chain it to the Root CA that's installed in your trust-anchor store.

Your *Unaffected PC* is showing the symptom of a Windows computer which conveniently has the subordinate CA certificates cached in its certificate store.  These are usually placed there when a user browses to another website which uses the same subordinate CAs but whose administrator knows what they are doing :-)  The PC is still only receiving the end-entity certificate from the server, but as it has the subordinate CAs certificates cached, it can join them together and build the chain.

Now, Windows has a facility to download any subordinate CAs from a repository, but this will only work if (a) the URL of this repository is contained within the certificate, (b) the certificate is actually installed on that repository, and (c) the repository is online and accessible.

To resolve this, you need to have a stern word with the administrator of the website and tell them to read [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).  Specifically, [section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2).

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's a problem with the web server. https://www.bookkeepers.org.uk and https://uk.godaddy.com use the same root and intermediate CA certificates (verified by checking thumbprints / hashes) but the former doesn't work and the latter does work. Interestingly, the intermediate CA certificate was still not installed but I guess that that's because it follows the chain up to the root which is sufficient. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bookkeepers.org.uk&latest backs this up too - `No trust paths available. Issuer unknown, or intermediate certificate(s) missing.`

Comment: For the long-term, I've emailed Institute of Certified Bookkeepers and, in the short term, I've manually imported the missing certificate (obtained from https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/ | `GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G2` | `gdig2.crt (der)` | https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt.